# Mysqli always returns number as string

Tags: php, mysql, string, pdo, mysqli

I have problem with mysqli. When I query the data, mysqli always returns a string.

In my database there is a table "model":

```
CREATE TABLE Models
(
    id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ;
```

My PHP code

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$database);
$resultSql = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM models');

$resultArray = array();
while($row =  $resultSql->fetch_assoc()) {
     array_push($resultArray,$row);
}
print(gettype($resultArray[0]['id']));
```

And print() returns to me "string". But field "id" in the database has integer data type. I was looking for some settings, but could not find it.

I tried using PDO, but I ran into the same problem. If you know the solution for PDO, I'll be happy.

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: i don't think u can do anything about it except casting to int in php

Comment: I haven't tried it, but check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5014667/42139

Comment: @jeroen bind_result - great method, is returns integer. Thx! But method has a fixed number of parameters. If the query returns three columns, then the method must have 3 parameters. I wanted to make a universal code, but now I do not know how.

Comment: you don't need bind_result. get_result is all right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was looking for some settings, but could not find it.

You have to use mysqlnd-based prepared statements to get ints.

> If you know the solution for PDO, I'll be happy.

Again, mysqlnd-based PDO installation is required

Comment: Thanks for the response. get_result helps me.